# Why Linq Query Return Duplicate column record

Tags: angularjs, linq, wcf

I am consuming wcf rest service into angular js application.I am trying to join three linq queries into single query and display the records into an angular js application. But the problem is when I enter the account number and click the submit button, it also displays the same record again and again. Instead of showing same record i want to display empty row .

Here is the Linq Query:

```
        public string TranscationDetails(string Account_Number)
        {

            var accountNumber = int.Parse(Account_Number);//It could be better to use TryParse
            using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
            {


                var inOut = context.Current_Account_Withdraw.Select(w => new {
                    w.Account_Number
                ,
                    Deposit = (decimal?)null
                ,
                    Withdrawal = (decimal?)w.Amount
                ,
                    w.Date
                }).Concat(context.Current_Account_Deposit.Select(d => new {
                    d.Account_Number
                ,
                    Deposit = (decimal?)d.Amount
                ,
                    Withdrawal = (decimal?)null
                ,
                    d.Date
                }))

                .Where(r => r.Account_Number == accountNumber)
                .OrderBy(r => r.Date)
                .ToList();

//                var summary = inOut.GroupBy(i => i.Account_Number).Select(g => new
//                {
//                    Account_Number = g.Key
//,
//                    Balance = g.Sum(x => x.Deposit ?? 0M - x.Withdrawal ?? 0M)
//,
//                    TotalDeposits = g.Sum(x => x.Deposit ?? 0M)
//,
//                    TotalWithdrawals = g.Sum(x => x.Withdrawal ?? 0M)
//                });
                var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

                    return js.Serialize(inOut); // return JSON string




            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Here is the screen shot when i clicked the button with account number and Linq query also display the expected [image]record. 
**I want Grant total Money In at bottom of row and Money Out total at bottom as well with the account record.**

But When i combine both query .

```
   public string TranscationDetails(string Account_Number)
        {

            var accountNumber = int.Parse(Account_Number);//It could be better to use TryParse
            using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
            {


                var inOut = context.Current_Account_Withdraw.Select(w => new {
                    w.Account_Number
                ,
                    Deposit = (decimal?)null
                ,
                    Withdrawal = (decimal?)w.Amount
                ,
                    w.Date
                }).Concat(context.Current_Account_Deposit.Select(d => new {
                    d.Account_Number
                ,
                    Deposit = (decimal?)d.Amount
                ,
                    Withdrawal = (decimal?)null
                ,
                    d.Date
                }))

                .Where(r => r.Account_Number == accountNumber)
                .OrderBy(r => r.Date)
                .ToList();

                var summary = inOut.GroupBy(i => i.Account_Number).Select(g => new
                {
                    Account_Number = g.Key
,
                    Balance = g.Sum(x => x.Deposit ?? 0M - x.Withdrawal ?? 0M)
,
                    TotalDeposits = g.Sum(x => x.Deposit ?? 0M)
,
                    TotalWithdrawals = g.Sum(x => x.Withdrawal ?? 0M)
                });
                var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

                    return js.Serialize(summary); // return JSON string




            }
        }
```

I get this result .[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are bringing in the same tables more than once. Assuming that there are multiple deposits and multiple withdrawals for the same `Account_Details` item, you need to group the results by account number.

Here is a corrected version:

```
var CombinedQuery = (
    from a in context.Current_Account_Details
    join w in context.Current_Account_Withdraw on w.Account_Number equals a.Account_Number
    join d in context.Current_Account_Deposits on d.Account_Number equals a.Account_Number
    where a.Account_Number == accountNumber
    group new {a, w, d} by a.Account_Number into g
    select new {
        Account_Number = g.Key
    ,   DepositAmount = g.Sum(i => i.d.Amount)
    ,   WithdrawalAmount = g.Sum(i => i.w.Amount)
    ,   Account_Balance = g.Sum(i => i.a.Account_Balance)
    }
).ToList();
```

> First I want to display records like bank account monthly Money In and Money out statement

Then you could do it without grouping or joining, like this:

```
var inOut = context.Current_Account_Withdraw.Select(w => new {
    w.Account_Number
,   Deposit = (decimal?)null
,   Withdrawal = (decimal?)w.Amount
,   w.Date
}).Concat(context.Current_Account_Deposit.Select(d => new {
    d.Account_Number
,   Deposit = (decimal?)d.Amount
,   Withdrawal = (decimal?)null
,   d.Date
}))
.Where(r => r.Account_Number == accountNumber)
.OrderBy(r => r.Date)
.ToList();
```

The above query concatenates deposits and withdrawals, and orders them by date.

Now you can compute the totals in memory:

```
var summary = inOut.GroupBy(i => i.Account_Number).Select(g => new {
    Account_Number = g.Key
,   Balance = g.Sum(x => x.Deposit ?? 0M - x.Withdrawal ?? 0M)
,   TotalDeposits = g.Sum(x => x.Deposit ?? 0M)
,   TotalWithdrawals = g.Sum(x => x.Withdrawal ?? 0M)
});
```

Comment: @Mohammad Since you are selecting individual records anyway, you would be better off adding them up in memory.

Comment: @Mohammad Please look at the comments to your follow-up question, they explain what's wrong, and suggest a fix. Your summary row has a different structure from the transaction row, you can't push both in a single table without unifying element types, names, and order inside a union / concat.